# Get a formatted date cell from Excel Sheet in PHP

Tags: php, excel

I read a excel sheet using Excel Reader and now i am unable to show a cell information because it is formatted cell. It is a data cell.

In php how can i show the date as in excel sheet?

In Excel The cell is like: `10-Apr-1956 (Date formatted)`

In php now it show like: `20555 (the general form)`

How to show in the form of date in php?

Answer (score 0):

`20555` is an Excel representation of the date. It's not a general form and is similar to the unix timestamp. I understand it to be the number of days since January 1, 1900.

So you will need to have a function that can covert this. I would think that something like the following could work:

```
function convertExcelDateNumberToUnixTimestamp($dateNumber){
    /*     Jan 1 1900  + [number of days in seconds] */
    return -2208988800 + (24 * 60 * 60 * $dateNumber);
}

function formatExcelDateNumberToDate($dateNumber) {
    /*Where 'l jS \of F Y' is whatever format you want:*/
    return date('l jS \of F Y', convertExcelDateNumberToUnixTimestamp($dateNumber);
}
```

With the first function you can use the response to construct a `DateTime` object.

Answer (score 0):

Excel stores dates and times as a figure representing the days since 1900-Jan-0, with fractional part of a 24 hour day.

As for solution you can use following code snippet,

```
$excel_date = 20555; // Serialized form of 10-Apr-1956
$processDate = $excel_date - 25569;
$dateVal = strtotime("+$processDate days", mktime(0,0,0,1,1,1970));
echo date('d M Y', $dateVal);
```